# Stored Proc hangs when no rows exist in cursor?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-8.0, cursors

I'm on 8.0.19 if that matters.
Here is my test proc:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `testNullProc`()
main:BEGIN
    DECLARE fileID INTEGER;
    DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT FALSE;     
    DECLARE records INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    
  
    DECLARE idCur 
        CURSOR FOR 
            select distinct fileHash from ud_fileinfo 
                LEFT JOIN ud_distinctfiles2 ON 
                fileID = fileHash
                where
                fileID is null; 
      DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = TRUE;
    
    
    OPEN idCur;      
    
    
    main_loop: LOOP     
        FETCH idCur INTO fileID;
        IF finished THEN 
            LEAVE main_loop;
        END IF; 
                          
        call debug_msg(TRUE, CONCAT('current FileID is ', fileID));         
        
    END LOOP main_loop;     
    CLOSE idCur;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The select stmt for idCur should only returns rows from the right table when they do not exist in the left table. Currently the result is 0 rows because there is no difference because there are no new rows but in production every iteration should result in some new rows, depending upon the frequency.

Anyway, what I'm expecting to happen is the proc to terminate because there aren't any rows in the cursor. However, what I have consistently observed is that the proc will hang when somewhere, either when declaring the cursor, opening the cursor or selecting the count rows either a local variable or a user defined variable. I've also tried stuff like:

```
...
...
SELECT count(*) INTO records from (select distinct fileHash from ud_fileinfo 
                        LEFT JOIN ud_distinctfiles2 ON 
                        fileID = fileHash
                        where
                        fileID is null)x;                       
                        
    
    
    IF (records = 0) THEN
     LEAVE main;
    END IF;
```

But the result is the same. I'm new to MySQL stored procedures but from what I've read in the MySQL documentation and the Internet in general, it doesn't appear that I'm doing anything incorrectly.

Comment: there are a lot if questiin as hash is never an integer so how should it fit, also iam pretty sure that your query is wrong, so give the where clause somethung correct like 'test' to work work with and see what   datatype is fileid and make the local variable thesame

Comment: Create a https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0 that demonstrates the problem

Comment: @nbk the query isn't wrong. fileHash is just a column name. what is in the column is what matters and it is an integer.

Comment: what type is fileHash  exactly

Comment: @nbk fileHash is in integer. The tables in this database are populated by an application i wrote in java. the application (among other things) generates a hashcode to create a unique signature for each file. That signature is an int stored in the filehash column. The procedure i'm debugging takes a snapshot of that table to generate a unique list of files. The table in production contains over .5 b rows.

Comment: giva an create table with some data; i will debug it.

Answer (score 2):

OK I think I understand what was happening. Lesson learned -- local variable declarations collide in some way with column names in any DDL or DML within the procedure.

Altering my procedure and changing variable fileID (which happens to be a column in a table I reference) to a different value, I get the result I'm expecting.